# Type.GetType("System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding" returns null

Tags: wcf, reflection, basichttpbinding, gettype

I would like to know why do I need to pass AssemblyQualifiedName to create any instance of basic http binding. I saw same behavior with ServiceModel.EndPointAddress.

When I pass assembly name, it returns null

string binding = "System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding";
Type.GetType(binding); // Returns null

If I pass AssemblyQualifiedName, it works fine.

string binding = "System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
Type.GetType(binding); returns object

Answer (score 0):

That's what `GetType` is documented as using, unless the type is a core type, or is the current executing assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx

> **Parameters**
>
> *typeName*
>
> *Type: System.String*
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>   AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.